# How can I delete and edit a specific node within a XML file by using php?

Tags: php, xml

How can I delete and edit a specific node within a XML file by using php?
please healp me anybody!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457153/how-do-i-remove-a-specific-node-using-its-attribute-value-in-php-xml-dom).
Also, [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlphp2.html) describes a few different methods to work with an XML document in php.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [DOM](http://sg.php.net/dom) library to traverse and manipulate XML documents.

Before you can delete or edit a node, you will need to load your XML document into a DOMDocument object:

```
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->load('youfile.xml');
```

There are many ways to find the node you are after. One of them is performing a query using the XPath for the node:

```
$xmlPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$xmlNodes = $xmlPath->query('//graphics');
```

$xmlNodes is an array of [DOMElements](http://sg.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php). They have their own functions to delete or edit the particular nodes you are after.

For example you can get all of them and delete certain attributes:

```
foreach($xmlNodes as $node)
{
    $node->removeAttribute('size');
}
```

Once you are done, you can save your changes to file:

```
$domDocument->save('yourfile.xml');
```

Comment: is there graphics is the name of the node? can you please tell me with the following xml file?
<new>
<message id='1'>
 <first>Abisha</first>
 <last>MG</last>
 <company>Zen</company>
 <email>abisha@zen-e-solutions.com</email>
 <gender>Female</gender>
</message>
</new>
i want edit Abisha means?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the xml2array function, and then threat it like an array:

```
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1){
if(!$contents) return array();
if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')){
    print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!";
    return array();
}
//Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work
$parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parser_set_option( $parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0 );
xml_parser_set_option( $parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1 );
xml_parse_into_struct( $parser, $contents, $xml_values );
xml_parser_free( $parser );
if(!$xml_values) return;//Hmm...
//Initializations
$xml_array = array();
$parents = array();
$opened_tags = array();
$arr = array();
$current = &$xml_array;
//Go through the tags.
foreach($xml_values as $data){
    unset($attributes,$value);//Remove existing values, or there will be trouble
    //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope
    // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array).
    extract($data);//We could use the array by itself, but this cooler.
    $result = '';
    if($get_attributes){//The second argument of the function decides this.
        $result = array();
        if(isset($value)) $result['value'] = $value;
        //Set the attributes too.
        if(isset($attributes)){
            foreach($attributes AS $attr => $val){
                if($get_attributes == 1) $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr'
                /**  :TODO: should we change the key name to '_attr'? Someone may use the tagname 'attr'. Same goes for 'value' too */
            }
        }
    }else if(isset($value)){
        $result = $value;
    }
    //See tag status and do the needed.
    if($type == "open"){//The starting of the tag '<tag>'
        $parent[$level-1] = &$current;
        if(!is_array($current) OR (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))){//Insert New tag
            $current[$tag] = $result;
            $current = &$current[$tag];
        }else{ //There was another element with the same tag name
            if(isset($current[$tag][0])){
                array_push($current[$tag], $result);
            }else{
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);
            }
            $last = count($current[$tag]) - 1;
            $current = &$current[$tag][$last];
        }
    }else if($type == "complete"){//Tags that ends in 1 line '<tag />'
        //See if the key is already taken.
        if(!isset($current[$tag])){//New Key
            $current[$tag] = $result;
        }else{//If taken, put all things inside a list(array)
            if((is_array($current[$tag]) and $get_attributes == 0)//If it is already an array...
                    or (isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag][0]) and $get_attributes == 1)){
                array_push($current[$tag],$result); // ...push the new element into that array.
            }else{//If it is not an array...
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value
            }
        }
    }else if($type == 'close'){ //End of tag '</tag>'
        $current = &$parent[$level-1];
    }
}
return($xml_array);
}
```

Comment: i used it to parse xml to array and editted the array. how will i change the array to xml?

Comment: You need the function inverse, array2xml.
You can try this to:
http://phpclasses.burina.net/browse/package/2286.html
http://snipplr.com/view/3491/convert-php-array-to-xml-or-simple-xml-object-if-you-wish/
or else, write down your own function to fulfill your needs...
Oh, give at look to this one to:

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML was new to PHP 5.

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
?>
```

Once your XML is loaded into a simpleXML object you can locate the specific node and 'unset' it to delete it.