# Remove multiple empty nodes with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I want to delete all the empty nodes in my XML document using `SimpleXML`

Here is my code :

```
$xs = file_get_contents('liens.xml')or die("Fichier XML non chargé");
$doc_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xs);
foreach($doc_xml->xpath('//*[not(text())]') as $torm)
    unset($torm);   
$doc_xml->asXML("liens.xml");
```

I saw with a `print_r()` that XPath is grabbing something, but nothing is removed from my XML file.

Comment: I do not believe that you are actually unset()'ing on the element in $doc_xml. Let me look up SimpleXML to see how to properly remove a node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SimpleXML - Remove xpath node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442314/php-simplexml-remove-xpath-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this post is a bit old but in your `foreach`, `$torm` is replaced in every iteration.  This means your `unset($torm)` is doing nothing to the original `$doc_xml` object.

Instead you will need to remove the element itself:

```
foreach($doc_xml->xpath('//*[not(text())]') as $torm)
    unset($torm[0]);
               ###
```

by using a *simplxmlelement-self-reference*.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file  = 'liens.xml';
$xpath = '//*[not(text())]';

if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)) {
    throw new Exception("Fichier XML non chargé");
}

foreach ($xml->xpath($xpath) as $remove) {
    unset($remove[0]);
}

$xml->asXML($file);
```

Comment: `dom_import_simplexml()` is not necessary, you can remove the element node directly with `unset` in simplexml without switching to DOM ([simplexml self reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4137027/367456)).