# Can't read an XML file with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have been trying to read the xml file, but it is giving me a strange error.
My XML is as follows

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<response>
    <url>http://xyz.com</url>
    <token>xxxxxxx<token>
</response>
```

To read this I am using

```
simplexml_load_string(variable containing xml goes here)
```

but it is giving me this error

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in 
>   on line 47
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: 1
>   in  on line 47
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^
>   in  on line 47

Comment: What encoding are you using to save your xml file? Or is the XML saved in a variable? Also, this `<token>xxxxxxx<token>` is not well-formed xml.

Comment: Same errors on codepad.org: http://codepad.org/0AsEZK8J
There is a missing slash!

Comment: I am not saving the file here.I get this xml as a response from an API.My page encoding is <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and doc type is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

Comment: I dont understand.where is the slash missing?

Comment: @hakre what about `simplexml_load_string()`?... knowing the source string is required to find out the actual problem, BOM or otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanx all for the attention and replies,
But the problem lied somewhere else
In my curl request the i had not set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true and that was causing the XML not to be recorded in the variable and was somehow was getting printed on the screen giving the illusion that it is coming from the variable but it was not.
However i set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 1 and it is giving me correct results now.
Sorry for the silly mistake.
and thanx all.

Answer (score 3):

The response you get from the API is not well-formed/valid XML:

```
<token>xxxxxxx<token>
              ^ missing /
```

As this is an API response you need to fix it prior simplexml can actually read it in. You *can* make use of the [tidy extension <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) to solve this:

```
$config = Array(
    'input-xml' => 1,
);
$xml = tidy_repair_string($xml, $config);

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$doc = dom_import_simplexml($xmlObj)->ownerDocument;

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

foreach($xpath->query('//token[not(node())]') as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

echo $xmlObj->asXML();
```

This will produce the following XML by first fixing unclosed tags and then removing empty `token` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
<url>http://xyz.com</url>
<token>xxxxxxx
</token>
</response>
```

Related:

- [PHP SimpleXML - Remove xpath node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442314/php-simplexml-remove-xpath-node)

Comment: It's always the simple things. >.<;;;

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly pointed out, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER set to 1 is very important!

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $postUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 ); // set to 1 for debugging
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return from sms server
```