# PHP DOM - Parse text nodes that contain certain HTML tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, nodes

I recently received help in parsing all text nodes from an HTML document.  The resulting code was this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($contents);
$doc->loadHTML("<p>not in the brackets..</p>");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$textnodes = $xpath->evaluate('//text()');
```

Using the following extract:

```
<p>This is a <b>nested <i>HTML</i> tag<b>...</p>
```

I am able to create an array of elements:

```
Array
(
  [0] => This is a 
  [1] => nested
  [2] => HTML
  [3] => tag
  [4] => ...
)
```

What I would actually like to do, though, is to retrieve all text nodes **but to allow certain HTML tags to be 'looked over'**.  For instance, I do not want `<i>`, `<b>` and `<u>` tags to be parsed as individual nodes; I would rather they are joined on to the previous text node.  The above array would, ideally, look like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => This is a nested HTML tag...
)
```

On the other hand, the `<p>` tags *should* be recognised as separate nodes.  So the following text:

```
<p>paragraph 1 <b>here</b></p> <p>paragraph 2</b>
```

Would ideally be parsed as:

```
Array
(
  [0] => paragraph 1 <b>here</b>
  [1] => paragraph 2
```

I have done some reading about XPath and the PHP DOM, but honestly, I don't really have a clue how to go about this.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

**Edit**

Just to clarify the output must be in array format; my aim is to parse all text from a page so it can then be used in a translation file.  Certain HTML tags (`<b>`, etc) are therefore desirable in the parsed text in order to keep full sentences together - and to keep the markup roughly intact - in the new translation file.

Comment: Possible duplicate.  Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442314/php-simplexml-remove-xpath-node

Comment: @Calvin Unless I am misunderstanding that article, the question is not asking the same thing as I am.

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Comment: @pguardiario Again, I don't think that's asking the same thing?  If I can use the answer to achieve my aim, I don't see how.  Please advise further.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on the 'looked over tags' and using the second parameter of the allowable tags on the ones you want to actually split by.

Comment: I can't use `strip_tags()` because I need to retrieve the text inside the HTML markup as an array. Removing the tags that will serve to 'delimit' the array will only make it harder to do so.  Perhaps I have omitted some information in my question, though, so I'll edit it now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a node and want to normalize it as plain text:

```
XPATH: 'string(thenode)'
DOM:   $thenode->textContent;
```

This will ignore all child nodes which are not text nodes and return it as a single string.

So in your example, an xpath like `string(//p)` will get you an array of plain text paragraphs with all elements removed. You could do the same thing with the DOM using `getElementsByTagName()` and fetching `textContent` property for each result.

If you have requirements more complex than this you might be better off using XSL with an identity transform to generate a new DOM tree that's more to your liking.  For example, if you have some top-level nodes you want (like `<p>`), and want to strip out some but not all of its subnodes (e.g., "keep `em` and `strong`, but collapse `cite` upward), then a DOM solution will be quite tedious.