# Removing parent nodes based on child in XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML which looks like the following:

```
$data = '<search-params>
  <date>2013-05-20</date>
</search-params>
<results>
  <date>2013-05-21 14:31:00</date>
  <prices>
   <for>
    <players>1</players>
   </for>
   <amount>20</amount>
  </prices>
  <prices>
   <for>
    <players>2</players>
   </for>
   <amount>35</amount>
  </prices>
  <prices>
   <for>
    <players>3</players>
   </for>
   <amount>49.5</amount>
  </prices>
  <prices>
   <for>
    <players>4</players>
   </for>
   <amount>60</amount>
  </prices>
 </results>
 <results>
  <date>2013-05-21T14:40:00</date>
  <prices>
   <for>
    <players>1</players>
   </for>
   <amount>20</amount>
  </prices>
 </results>';
```

Now, what I want to do is to strip out some of that based on a rule.

So, If I have `<players>` child node of 4, it should only return the `<results>` nodes that have that value.

Is this possible in in PHP?

I can load that using `simplexml_load_string($data)`. The problem is how to find the information and remove the nodes.

Thanks

Comment: **[XPath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)**

Comment: Yes, it is possible in PHP with XPath. And yes, simplexml supports xpath 1.0. To remove a node with simplexml, please see: [PHP SimpleXML - Remove xpath node](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2442314/367456) and [Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/262351/367456). -1 from my end because this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody answered, so i will. Please, read the comments.

```
// First, your XML must be wraped with some root tag.
$data = '<root>
    <search-params>
        <date>2013-05-20</date>
    </search-params>
    <results>
        <date>2013-05-21 14:31:00</date>
        <prices>
            <for>
                <players>1</players>
            </for>
            <amount>20</amount>
        </prices>
        <prices>
            <for>
                <players>2</players>
            </for>
            <amount>35</amount>
        </prices>
        <prices>
            <for>
                <players>3</players>
            </for>
            <amount>49.5</amount>
        </prices>
        <prices>
            <for>
                <players>4</players>
            </for>
            <amount>60</amount>
        </prices>
    </results>
    <results>
        <date>2013-05-21T14:40:00</date>
        <prices>
            <for>
                <players>1</players>
            </for>
            <amount>20</amount>
        </prices>
    </results>
</root>';

// Instancing the SimpleXMLElement within the XML(obviously)
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

// XPath
$xpath = $xml->xpath("results[prices/for[contains(players,'4')]]"); 
/**
 * eXplained XPath:
 *      <results> that 
 *          <prices>/<for>
 *              contains <players> that content is equal 4
 */

foreach($xpath as $node){
    // just for fun echoes the <results> node
    echo $node->asXml();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! How would I then access the `<date>` value of the `<results>` node?

Comment: `$date = $node->xpath('date');` `echo $date[0];`

Comment: @UltimateProgrammer_BR: Please do not feed Help Vampires. They don't want to understand, they just want to ask more. What I want to say is: Answering is not always an opportunity.

Comment: I understand your point, @hakre :P

Comment: One further point. What If I wanted to 'filter' by the `amount` field? So If I wanted all results that have 1 player, but the amount is `30 or above`?

Comment: Just search for `XPath Syntax` on Google.

Comment: Thank you. That's really helped with my application!