# XPath in PHP - SimpleXMLElement key numeric instead of textual

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I have the following XML saved in $string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<users>
  <user id="1">
    <name>Michael Tray</name>
    <account>473.43</account>
  </user>
  <user id="2">
    <name>Sandra Marry</name>
    <account>154.24</account>
  </user>
</users>
```

I use the following simple XPath expression to get all names

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$result = $xml->xpath("/users/user/name");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

What I get

```
Array (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Michael Tray
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => Sandra Marry
        )
)
```

What I want

```
Array (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => Michael Tray
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => Sandra Marry
        )
)
```

So the SimpleXMLElement key should be a string (tag name) and not a number. How can I do that?

Comment: Why did you think the key should be a string (tag name)? (just curious, could also add some useful context to your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual with SimpleXML, `print_r` is lying to you. The objects don't really have a "key" of 0 at all.

Each object actually represent a single XML element, and you can access the tag name using [`getName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php), and the string content with a `(string)` cast, as follows:

```
foreach ( $result as $node ) {
    echo 'Name: ', $node->getName(), '; ';
    echo 'Content: ', (string)$node, '<br />';
}
```

(The `(string)` is actually redundant with `echo`, because it forces things to string anyway, but is important to remember anywhere else to avoid passing around the whole object by mistake.)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!

Comment: Actually it does have a "key" of 0. More correctly every **SimpleXMLElement** which represents an *existing* node in the document does have. Just saying, that `print_r` is lying is totally true :)

Comment: @hakre True, you can access `$node[0]`; and because that just returns itself, you can also access `$node[0][0]` and `$node[0][0][0]`, and `$node[0][0][0][0]`...

Comment: Yes, that's what I often call the SimpleXMLElement self-reference. Useful for example to [delete the node itself. E.g. with an xpath result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2442314/367456).