# Remove a xml node in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

my xml file:

```
<temporary>
  <users>
    <temp>
      <id>1</id>
      <title> Undercover</title>
      <author>Wiwit</author>
    </temp>
    <nissi>
      <confirm>3977678bce8515e8cdbfa64850904ad1</confirm>
      <firstname>hi</firstname>
      <lastname>hhey</lastname>
      <day>1</day>
    </nissi>
   </users>
</temporary>
```

my php:

```
<?php
$user="nissi";
$xml = simplexml_load_file("temporary.xml") 
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
unset($xml->temporary->users->$user);
?>
```

Why is this not  working.
The unset is not working.The node ins'nt getting deleted.

Comment: What fails? The file loading or the `unset()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like this :

```
$user="nissi";
$xml = simplexml_load_file("temporary.xml") 
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
unset($xml->users->$user);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

You mustn't take the root of your xml in the "request" `temporary` here.

[DEMO HERE](http://codepad.org/VRe8KIMl)

Comment: Exactly! Use the $xml object to proof!

Comment: Just call the variable the same name as the root node, it will prevent that kind of mixups.

Comment: @Josh Davis : It's a great advice for beginners :)

Comment: Yeah, that's just about the best advice I can ever give to any SimpleXML user :) That, and also that they don't consider SimpleXMLElement as some kind as array that they can inspect with `print_r()` but that one is a bit too cryptic.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do it with SimpleXML alone, you have to use DOMElement conversion as explained here:

[Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php)

Comment: That's true. But here, there's no attribute in his XML :)