# Unable to add Attribute with Namespace Prefix using PHP Simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xml-namespaces

Trying to edit an XML document that uses Excels XML-Namespaces:

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
          xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
```

I need to get to this result (need the **ss:** prefix befire **Type**):

```
<Cell ...><Data ss:Type="String">value</Data></Cell>
```

I've looked over the question [*Unable add namespace with PHPs SimpleXML*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592665/unable-add-namespace-with-phps-simplexml) but this method is not helping here. In other words, running this as outlined there

```
$data = $cells[$i]->addChild('Data','value'); 
$data->addAttribute("ss:Type","String","urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
```

gives me

```
<Cell ...><Data Type="String">value</Data></Cell>
```

without the **ss:** prefix. And if I remove the **urn:** prefix, then I'm getting this

```
<Cell ...><Data xmlns:ss="schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Type="String">value</Data></Cell>
```

In either case, when I open the document with Excel, the data is invisible.  With **urn:** the **ss:** is missing and without **urn:** the definition becomes part of the  element which is not working in Excel.

Comment: I am trying to do the same in java. Can you please help? <br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025799/add-namespace-to-java-dom-attribute

Answer (score 12):

If you want to add an attribute with a specific namespace prefix w/o adding the namespace to the document, you have to specify not only the prefix in the *name* parameter, but also prefix it again with `xmlns`, in my example: `xmlns:ss:Type`. The namespace URI (third parameter) then will be ignored as well, so it is not necessary either:

```
$data->addAttribute("xmlns:ss:Type", "String");
```

Note the **xmlns:** in front of **ss:Type**. The output then is as required:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="String">value</Data></Cell>
```

Comment: This helped solved my problem when building Excel files using simplexml in PHP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually set the namespace for the attribute, though the result when serialized with [`SimpleXMLElement->asXML()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.asXML) is equivalent. Instead, "ss:" is part of the [local part](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#NT-LocalPart) of the attribute name. Compare the output of `$data->attributes('ss', TRUE)` and `$data->attributes()`. You can also use any prefix, not just "xmlns".