# add namespace to java dom attribute

Tags: java

I am trying to create an attribute with a namespace prefix. The following code does not seem to work:

```
Element newData = docFromXML.createElement("Data");
Attr typeAttr = docFromXML.createAttributeNS(namespaceContext.getNamespaceURI("ss"), "type");
typeAttr.setValue("String");
newData.setAttributeNode(typeAttr);
```

I expect the following:

```
<Data ss:type="String"></Data>
```

But the following is produced:

```
<Data type="String"></Data>
```

How do I explicitely add the namespace prefix "ss". The getNamespaceURI function returns the URL for the ss prefix in the DOM.

Comment: I think I have figured out why it does not work. ss happens to be the default namespace in the root of the same DOM:

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

So how do I still add it explicitly? I still need it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
Attr typeAttr = docFromXML.createAttribute("ss:type");
```

It generates:

```
<Data ss:type="String"></Data>
```