# Removing an xml node using php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<uploads>
 <upload>
  <name>asd</name>
  <type>123</name>
 </upload>
 <upload>
  <name>qwe</name>
  <type>456</name>
 </upload>
</uploads>
```

Now I want to delete a node upload that has a name child as (say **qwe**). How can I delete it using php , so that the resulting xml is

```
<uploads>
 <upload>
  <name>asd</name>
  <type>123</name>
 </upload>
</uploads>
```

I do not have too much knowledge about xml and related techniques. Is it possible to do it using xpath, like this `$xml->xpath('//upload//name')`? Assuming `$xml` was loaded using `simplexml_load_file()` function.

For reference, I was using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php) to do what I want. But, it selects the element based on an attribute and I want to select an element based on the value of it child node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use XPath to find the node that is to be removed. You can use [predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) to specifiy the exact elements you're looking for. In your case the predicate can be `has a name element and its (string/node) value is 'qwe'`, like e.g.:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadxml( getData() );

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach( $xpath->query("/uploads/upload[name='qwe']") as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$doc->formatOutput = true;
echo $doc->savexml();


function getData() {
    return <<< eox
<uploads>
 <upload>
  <name>asd</name>
  <type>123</type>
 </upload>
 <upload>
  <name>qwe</name>
  <type>456</type>
 </upload>
</uploads>
eox;
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<uploads>
  <upload>
    <name>asd</name>
    <type>123</type>
  </upload>
</uploads>
```