# How to remove the element in xml using php depending on their node values

Tags: php, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rights>
 <visitor>
  <user>updateUsers</user>
  <user>deleteUsers</user>
  <user>createUsers</user>
  <user>readUsers</user>
 </visitor>
</rights>
```

This is the xml file i am using. I want to delete the nodes depending on their values. Eg if the user want me to remove the entry for **updateUsers** then i could remove the `<user>` that has value **updateUsers**.
I want to do it using php.
here is my script

```
$xmlobj=simplexml_load_file($xmlpath);

foreach($xmlobj->{$owner}[0]->children() as $mychild)
{
   $childvalues[]=$mychild;                    
}

foreach($childvalues as $values)
{
  if($userentry==$values)
  {
    //code to remove that node
  }
}
```

I am struck with it. Help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Look at the 1st 2 answers on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the child element from the parent node.

[PHP Simple XML remove all Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453282/php-simple-xml-remove-all-children?lq=1)