# Deleting simplexmlelement node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an xml file of this structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<my_events>
                        <event id="e20111129215359">
                            <title>the title</title>
                            <channel id="1">
                                <name>A name</name>
                                <onclick></onclick>
                            </channel>
                            <event_site>
                                <name/>
                                <url/>
                            </event_site>
                            <start_date>Thu Mar 08 2012</start_date>
                            <start_time>11:00 AM</start_time>
                            <end_date>null</end_date>
                            <end_time>null</end_time>
                            <notes>Notes for the event</notes>
                        </event>
 </my_events>
```

To delete an event, I have this php function.

```
<?php

include_once("phpshared.php");

function delete_event( $nodeid ) {

    $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('my_events.xml', LIBXML_NOCDATA, true);

    $node = $nodes->xpath("/my_events/event[@id='$nodeid']");

    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);

    $formatted = formatXmlString($nodes->asXML());
    $file = fopen ('my_events.xml', "w"); 
    fwrite($file, $formatted); 
    fclose ($file);  

}

echo delete_event(trim($_REQUEST['nodeid']));

?>
```

That doesn't delete the node.  Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `unset()`: [Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php)

Answer (score 19):

SimpleXML allows removal of elements via PHP's `unset()` keyword.

For your code snippet, simply replace

```
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

with

```
if ( ! empty($node)) {
    unset($node[0][0]);
}
```

If the XPath query returned a matching `<event>` element, we instruct SimpleXML to `unset()` it.

---

**Aside:** here are two occurrences of `[0]` because:

- `xpath()` returns an array, even if only one element matches. So `[0]` is used to get the first item in that array, which is the element we want to delete.
- The SimpleXMLElement returned from `$node[0]` represents a collection of `<event>` elements (but if you access elements/attributes on it then the values from the first in the collection is used). So, we use `[0]` to get at the actual `SimpleXMLElement` that we want to delete, which is the first in this magical collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I went with the other option because I want to be able to access the node as a DOM.

Comment: That's not what your question asked.

Comment: @salathe point about the second [0] index was particularly helpful and is a big gotcha.