# Remove sub-quoting in string

Tags: php, regex, tags, quote

I am making plugin for forum that delete over-quoting, so that there are only one level quotes:

```
<quote>
    <quote>subquote</quote>
    quote111
</quote>
text
<quote>quote222</quote>
text
```

`<quote>subquote</quote>` should be removed, because it is in another quote.

What is the best way to do it? I thought that this is widespread, but I cannot google it out.

It should be some crazy regexp. I can't wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **XML** then use it to loop at every `<quote>`.

When you have it in loop you can use [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) to remove subquotes.

You can use **SimpleXML** for that.

There's no need to use "crazy regexp"

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php) shows how to remove item with specific attribiute you can use it to fit your needs.

Comment: It is bbcode, i just change `[]` to `<>` while testing, so not to escape them. But yes, xml could be the way.

Answer (score 0):

I just did it with regexp, the easy way. Using negative lookeahead solved problem.

```
while ( preg_match("|<quote>((?!</quote>).)*?<quote>|us", $text) )
    $text = preg_replace("@(<quote>(?(?!quote>).)*?)<quote>(?(?!quote>).)*?</quote>@us", "$1", $text);
```

It checks if any subquotes left and remove one subquote in a time.