# PHP: Is it possible to pass xml node to function by ref and make change?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, byref

I wish to pass a xml node to a function by ref, and make change within the function. But seem the node's value couldn't be changed in this way.
Example:

```
<?php
$str = '<data><name>foo</name></data>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

test($xml->name);

echo $xml->name; //I expect it should be 'bar', but it is still 'foo'.

function test(&$node){  //it makes no difference if a '&' is added or not.
    $node = 'bar';
}
?>
```

Or if I made mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

You made a small mistake there: You are assigning the string `'bar'` to the variable reference `$node`, that is replacing the object (id) value named by that variable so far with a string. Instead you need to retain the object in that variable and only change the node-value of that `SimpleXMLElement`. That is done with a so called *self-reference*:

```
function test(&$node) {
    $node[0] = 'bar';
}
```

As you can see, this differs by adding `[0]` on that node. The `&` is not needed here actually as objects do not need to be passed by reference. Additionally you should hint the type as well:

```
function test(SimpleXMLElement $node) {
    $node[0] = 'bar';
}
```

And that's it, see the Demo: https://eval.in/108589 .

To better understand the magic behind this SimpleXMLElement self-reference here, please continue to read the [following answer which is about removing a node only by it's variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062633/367456) which is similar to setting the value of it. Take note that `SimpleXMLElement` is with *magic*, so things might not be intuitive on first sight.