# What is contained within the properties of a simpleXMLElement?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

## Problem 1: Accessing innerXHTML as a string

Imagine the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<feed>
  <title type="text">This is my title</title>
  <id>123456</id>
  <content>Hello World</content>
</feed>
```

Let's say we want to access the `<id>` value as a string.  One would think that could be accessed with:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
print_r($xml->id);
```

But that's not right, we'll end up just printing a new SimpleXMLElement, like so:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
   [0] => 123456
)
```

So we get back a new object of which 0 is a property, I guess?  There's two way that seem natural to access this, neither of which work:

```
//throws an error
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
print_r($xml->id->0);

//prints "SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 123456 )"
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
print_r($xml->id[0]);
```

So that leads to **question A: just what is inside of `$xml->id`?** It kind of acts like an object, but it also kind of acts like an array. Ultimately, there's two ways to access this value:

```
//prints '123456'
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$id = (array) $xml->id;
print_r($id[0]);

//prints '123456'
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
print_r($xml->id->__toString());
```

Of these, the second feels more "right" to me, but I'm left wondering just what is going on here.  **Question B: Why are `$xml->id` and `$xml->id[0]` identical?**  For that matter, why are `$xml->id[0]` and `$xml->id[0][0][0][0][0][0]` also identical?

## Problem 2: Dealing with multiple nodes of the same type

Imagine the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<feed>
  <title type="text">This is my title</title>
  <tag>news</tag>
  <tag>sports</tag>
  <content>Hello World</content>
</feed>
```

Suppose you want to get a list of all tags.  This is where I start to get really confused.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
print_r($xml->tag);
```

This has the following result:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => news
)
```

That's sensible enough, but this is the part I don't get.  We can also do this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
print_r($xml->tag[1]);
```

Which prints out this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => sports
)
```

What the hell?  If both tags are available inside `$xml->tag` then, **Question C: why doesn't `print_r($xml->tag)` print the following**:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [0] => news  
  [1] => sports
)
```

I guess `$xml->tag` implies `$xml->tag[0]`?  Ultimately, the only way I can see to access a list of all the `<tags>` is with xpath:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$tags = $xml->xpath('//tag');

//$tags is now an array of objects.  We want an array of strings.
foreach ($tags as &$tag) {
  $tag = (string) $tag;
}
print_r($tags);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => news
    [1] => sports
)
```

But that honestly seems like a lot of code to do something pretty simple and common.  So **Question D: is there a better way to get a list of values from XML natively in PHP?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### Problem 1: Accessing innerXHTML as a string

You access the inner-XML as a string for any **SimpleXMLElement** by *casting*  it to string:

```
print_r((string) $xml->id); # gives 123456
```

So, how does this work? This works because in PHP you can program any object that it can be casted into a string by making use of the [`__toString()` magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring). **SimpleXMLElement** is an internal object that does the same.

And why does the `print_r($xml->id)` look so strange? Well that is because `print_r` and `var_dump` on **SimpleXMLElement**\s are liars. So do not rely to them too much. **SimpleXMLElement** can lie here btw, because it is an internal object. It can deny the rules we couldn't when we write our own objects in PHP userspace.

> question A: just what is inside of $xml->id?

That is just an **SimpleXMLElement**. And it acts like an object that has implemented [*ArrayAccess*](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). So you can write objects that can be accessed like arrays. **SimpleXMLElement** does this as well.

It also override the standard casting to array. The exact rules that **SimpleXMLElement** will follow when cast to an array are somewhat not-so-intuitive (the best listing I did so far is with [SimpleXML and JSON Encode in PHP – Part I + II](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/simplexml-and-json-encode-in-php-part-i/) as the rules are the same as with JSON encoding, only if you're interested because you normally don't need that level of detail).

> Question B: Why are $xml->id and $xml->id[0] identical?

This is because `$xml->id` is an alias to the first `<id>` element, which is also accessible by it's numeric index: `$xml->id[0]`. This btw. allows you to access the element itself even it's in a single variable:

```
$id = $xml->id;

# change inner text
$id[0] = 'hello';   // $id = 'hello'; would have turned $id into a string

# remove the node from the tree
unset($id[0]);      // unset($id); would have unset the $id variable only
```

The `$id[0]` or `$id->{0}` notation is also sometimes called *simplexml self-reference*. A longer answer about it with some more references is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062633/367456 .

Btw, that is not *identical*. It's just two ways to access the same XML node in the document.

And for that matter: `$xml->id->{0}` would work, too. As would `$xml->id[0]->{0}` and even `$xml->id->{0}[0][0]->{0}[0]->{0}[0][0]->{0}[0]->{0}[0][0]->{0}[0]` and so on and so forth.

> ### Problem 2: Dealing with multiple nodes of the same type
>
> Question C: why doesn't print_r($xml->tag) print the following:

That is because due to the simplification SimpleXML does, it can't do both, so it needs to do a decision. Normally with `$xml->tag` you want to access the first element named `<tag>` and not all tags. However by casting you can give SimpleXML a hint what you want:

By casting to string, you basically say: give me the first elements value.

```
(string) $xml->tag; # news
```

By casting to array, you say: give me all elements values:

```
(array) $xml->tag # Array([0] => news, [1] => sports)
```

Which is perhaps already what you're asking for in

> Question D: is there a better way to get a list of values from XML natively in PHP?

That highly depends on your needs. As you have realized, the "simple" in SimpleXML comes with a lot of magic and is not always straight forward to understand. It's a condensed interface for some kind of typical XML parsing needs, but it can not cover all cases distinctively.

The DOM sister library allows you access more detailed with a DOMDocument based API which normally allows more fine-grained control if you need it.