# XML cleaning [xml:space] using PHP

Tags: php, xml

How to remove all nodes like xml:space="preserve" from XML, to get clean result

old XML

```
<table>
<actor xml:space="preserve"> </actor>
</table>
```

I want result be like this

```
<table>
<actor> </actor>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

this the php code

```
function produce_XML_object_tree($raw_XML) {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    try {
        $xmlTree = new SimpleXMLElement($raw_XML);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong.
        $error_message = 'SimpleXMLElement threw an exception.';
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error_line) {
            $error_message .= "\t" . $error_line->message;
        }
        trigger_error($error_message);
        return false;
    }
    return $xmlTree;
}
$xml_feed_url = "www.xmlpage.com/web.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$cont = produce_XML_object_tree($xml);

echo json_encode($cont);
```

Comment: *I want result be like this* Then go for it!

Comment: Have you made any attempts? What was the result? What did you try to fix it?

Comment: @Rizier123 I convert XML result to JSON from a web. But when it converted if any field has xml:space it return error

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Read my comment please above

Comment: What is the php code generating the xml. I assume it is a php code, isn't it?

Comment: @valiD I edit the post, see it please

Comment: Coding language and existing code please.
"I want to write my name in capital laters"
For "VALID" - just pressed CAPS
You only have to press delete "xml:space="preserve"" if those are the only details you are wiling to offer.

Comment: maybe with `str_replace` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @steven example please ?

Comment: did you follow the link? there are many examples.... however: `$xml = str_replace('xml:space="preserve"', "", $xml);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) expression to locate the attributes and remove them.

---

#### Example:

```
//$xml = your xml string

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//@xml:space') as $attr) {
    $attr->ownerElement->removeAttributeNode($attr);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

---

#### Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
<actor> </actor>
</table>
```

---

This will remove any xml:space attributes. If you want to target only those xml:space attributes that have a value of "preserve", change the query to `//@xml:space[.="preserve"]`.

Answer (score 0):

$string =    str_ireplace('xml:space="preserve"','',$string);

```
function produce_XML_object_tree($raw_XML) {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    try {
        $xmlTree = new SimpleXMLElement($raw_XML);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something went wrong.
        $error_message = 'SimpleXMLElement threw an exception.';
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error_line) {
            $error_message .= "\t" . $error_line->message;
        }
        trigger_error($error_message);
        return false;
    }
    return str_ireplace('xml:space="preserve"','',$xmlTree;);
}
$xml_feed_url = "www.xmlpage.com/web.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_feed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$cont = produce_XML_object_tree($xml);

echo json_encode($cont);
```

Comment: @valiD doesn't work return like this "\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n"

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're concerned to remove all attribute-nodes that are with a namespace prefix, you can do so by selecting them via xpath and remove them from the XML document.

The xpath query for all attributes with a prefix can be obtained by comparing the name (that is prefix and local-name) with the local-name (that is the local-name only). If it differs you've got a match:

```
//@*[name(.) != local-name(.)]
```

Querying specific nodes with SimpleXML and XPath to delete them has been [outlined earlier as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062633/367456) to the question [*Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP* (Nov 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/262351/367456) and is pretty straight-forward by using the *SimpleXML-Self-Reference*:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//@*[name(.) != local-name(.)]') as $attr) {
    unset($attr[0]);
}
```

The self-reference here is to remove the attribute `$attr` via `$attr[0]`.

Full Example:

```
$buffer = <<<XML
<table>
<actor class="foo" xml:space="preserve"> </actor>
</table>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//@*[name(.) != local-name(.)]') as $attr) {
    unset($attr[0]);
}
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Example Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
<actor class="foo"> </actor>
</table>
```