# How to delete SimpleXMLElement while iterating? (php)

Tags: php

I load and run a cycle through my XML structure:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(flakk);
foreach ($xml->class as $class)
{
    now how to delete $class ???
}
```

the `unset($class)` has no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant remove foreach element, but can for example so

```
for($i=count($xml->class); $i--; ) unset($xml->class[$i]);
```

Or

```
for($i=count($xml->class); $i--; )  
   if ($xml->class[$i] == AnyValue)   
       unset($xml->class[$i]);
```

Comment: I think that foreach($values as $k=>&$v) does make you unset($v) or at-least unset($values[$k])

Comment: first `foreach($values as $k=>&$v)` does not work. 2nd - maybe

Comment: tested, 2nd does not work too. In loop `foreach($xml->class as $k=>$v)` $k is `class` - name of node