# How can I delete from xml in foreach?

Tags: php, xml, unset

I have xml file.

```
<shop>
 <categories>
    <category id="132">kids</category>
    <category id="62" parentId="133">women</category>
    <category id="172" parentId="1">men</category>
</categories>

<materials>
    <material id="1">one</material>
    <material id="2">two</material>
    <material id="3">soon</material>
</materials>

<offers>

        <offer id="41850" available="true">
            <price>3220</price>
            <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
            <date>2015-02-05</date>
        </offer>
        <offer id="41850" available="true">
            <price>3220</price>
            <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
            <date>2015-02-05</date>
        </offer>
        <offer id="41850" available="true">
            <price>3220</price>
            <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
            <date>2015-02-05</date>
        </offer>
    <offer id="77777" available="true">
            <price>3250</price>
            <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
            <date>2015-02-05</date>
        </offer>
    <offer id="41340" available="true">
            <price>3120</price>
            <currencyId>EUR</currencyId>
            <date>2015-02-05</date>
        </offer>
```

I need delete categories and materials. After that i need delete all offers which are not unique and write it to new xml file.

My problem. I can't delete not unique offers. Please help me! Thx. Here is my code.

```
 $url = 'test.xml';
$yml = simplexml_load_file($url);  
unset($yml->shop->categories);     
unset($yml->shop->materials);      

$itemid = '0'; 

foreach ($yml->shop->offers->offer as $item){
    $sravnit = $item['id'];  
    if("$sravnit" == "$itemid") {
        echo "$sravnit eq $itemid delete<br>";
        unset($yml->shop->offers->offer[$sravnit]); 
        continue; 
    else {echo "$sravnit not eq $itemid ";
    $itemid = $sravnit;
    echo "itemid to - $itemid <br>"; 
    }


 }
$yml->asXML('odd.xml');
```

Comment: Just build an array of IDs in the loop. If the ID is already in the array, you can delete it.

Comment: when i use unset($yml->shop->categories); it's work great, but when i use unset($yml->shop->offers->offer[$sravnit]); nothing works... (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax doesn't make sense in multiple ways:

```
unset($yml->shop->offers->offer[$sravnit]);
```

1. `<shop>` is your root node and that is represented by `$yml`.
   So the path is `$yml->offers->offer`
2. you can't select the `<offer>` with the id of `$sravnit` like this. It is wrong.
   Instead `SimpleXml` will select the *n<sup>th</sup>* node in a list like this:

   ```
   <drinks>
       <drink id="2">beer</drink>
       <drink id="5">wine</drink>
       <drink id="0">water</drink>
   </drinks>
   ```

   `echo $xml->drink[2];` is `water`, I'm sorry. Check it: https://eval.in/464564
   http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php is a recommended read.
3. use of `unset()`: see this answer [Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php/16062633#16062633) for a good in-depth demonstration on how to combine `xpath()` and `unset()` to delete specific nodes with `SimpleXml`.

In your case, you might first check for non-unique id-attributes in the `<offer>` nodes, and delete those in a second step.

**step #1: list of non-unique id**

1. Create an array of all id values with `xpath()` like this:

   ```
   $ids = $yml->xpath("//offer/@id");
   ```
2. `$ids`is an array of `SimpleXml`-elements, use `array_map()` to convert to integer values:

   ```
   $ids = array_map("intval", $ids);
   ```
3. To get the **non-unique** values of the array `$ids`:

   ```
   $ids = array_count_values($ids);
   ```

   will return an array with index = id and value = count:

   ```
   array(3) {
     [41850]=>int(3)
     [77777]=>int(1)
     [41340]=>int(1)
   }
   ```
4. a unique id has the value of 1, so let us delete all those:

   ```
   $ids = array_diff($ids, array(1));
   ```
5. Now you have an array with all non-unique id, let's flip index and value:

   ```
   $ids = array_flip($ids);
   ```

   This is the result:

   ```
   array(1) {
     [3]=>int(41850)
   }
   ```
6. Summary: let's write all previous steps in two lines:

   ```
   $ids = $yml->xpath("//offer/@id");
   $ids = array_flip(array_diff(array_count_values(array_map("intval", $ids)), array(1)));
   ```

**step #2: delete all `<offer>` with their `id` attribute in `$ids`:**
I will use `xpath()` to select the node, and `unset()` to delete it:

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    foreach ($xml->xpath("//offer[@id='$id']") as $item)
        unset ($item[0]);
}
```

See it in action: https://eval.in/464608

Comment: Awesome. I cannot thank you enough for your assistance. Thx!