# Remove XML element with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to remove the element of the XML file under certain condition:

example.xml:

```
<all>
- <item>
  <ProductID>46121</ProductID> 
  <Price1>50</Price1> 
  </item>
- <item>
  <ProductID>51151</ProductID> 
  <Price1>20</Price1> 
  </item>
</all>
```

php:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
$price  = $item->Price1;
if ($price < 50 ) { REMOVE THIS ITEM  } 
}
$xml->asXML("result.xml");
?>
```

I want if the price is less than 50 REMOVE THIS ITEM

result.xml to be:

```
<all>
- <item>
  <ProductID>46121</ProductID> 
  <Price1>50</Price1> 
  </item>
</all>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [removeChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) in the [DOM extension](http://en.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

With [dom_import_simplexml()](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php) you can convert your SimpleXMLElement into a DOMElement.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');

$toDelete = array();

foreach ($xml->item as $item) {

    $price  = $item->Price1;

    if ($price < 50 ) { 
        $toDelete[] = $item;
    } 
}

foreach ($toDelete as $item) {
    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($item);
    $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
}

echo $xml->asXML("result.xml");
```

output (live [here](http://codepad.org/vHZeYmbW))

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<all>
 <item>
  <ProductID>46121</ProductID> 
  <Price1>50</Price1> 
  </item>
</all>
```

Comment: This solution works only for the first found item.
If the items are more generate an error.

Comment: I suspect that this is because modifying the data while it's under iteration invalidates the iterator position... see my updates

Comment: Is it possible to add a second chek (work together with $price < 50)  as:
if ($ProductID == "46121") { 
        $toDelete[] = $item;
    }

Comment: yes `($item->Price1 < 50 ||  $item->ProductID == "46121") `

Answer (score 0):

Combine `xpath` to select all wanted `<item>`s with `unset` to remove an `<item>` from your `SimpleXml` object:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$items = $xml->xpath("/all/item[Price1 < 50]");
foreach ($items as $i) unset($i[0]);
```

Check the result with

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comments:

- the `xpath` expression is straightforward, the `[]` enclose the condition. `xpath` will return an array of `SimpleXml` elements to `$items`.
- to remove a node, I use the *self-reference-technique* as [discussed many times on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062633/2016456).

see it working: https://eval.in/481413