# How to remove XML tag based on child attribute using php?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, domdocument

I have an XML like below

```
<entries>
  <entry>
    <title lang="en">Sample</title>
    <entrydate>0</entrydate>
    <contents>0</contents>
    <entrynum>0</entrynum>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title lang="fr">Sample</title>
    <entrydate>1</entrydate>
    <contents>1</contents>
    <entrynum>1</entrynum>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

Is there a way in PHP to delete the parent node (`entry`) based on the title `lang` attribute? I need to keep only the `en` ones, so in this case I would need to get the XML without the second `entry` node.

I tried looking around but couldn't find any solution...

Comment: Have you tried to use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)?

Comment: Yes is the first thing I tried, I use it to retrieve values. But I can't find any example about parsing using the 'lang' attribute and also my more specific need of deleting the whole parent based on the child language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to parse string to XML document. Then use [`DOMXpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class to find target element in document and use [`DOMNode::removeChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) to remove selected element from document.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
// select target entry tag
$entry = $xpath->query("//entry[title[@lang='fr']]")->item(0);
// remove selected element
$entry->parentNode->removeChild($entry);
$xml = $doc->savexml();
```

You can check result in [demo](http://ideone.com/rGPCgS)

Comment: Hi yes this works as a starting base, thanks! I'm going to find a way to actually have it going through all the xml because with the item(0) it only removes the first one, while I need to do it for all the entries matching.

Comment: @gege If you have multiple `<title lang="fr">` in your document, remove `item(0)` and iterate `$entry` using `foreach()` and remove every item in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also read your file and generated new one with your modification

```
<?php
$entries = array('title' => "What's For Dinner",
'link' => 'http://menu.example.com/',
'description' => 'Choose what to eat tonight.');
print "<entries>\n";
foreach ($entries as $element => $content) {
print " <$element>";
print htmlentities($content);
print "</$element>\n";
}
print "</entries>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php#262556) answer, i.e.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('1.xml');

$del_items = [];
foreach ($xml->entry as $e) {
  $attr = $e->title->attributes();
  if ($attr && $attr['lang'] != 'en') {
    $del_items []= $e;
  }
}

foreach ($del_items as $e) {
  $dom = dom_import_simplexml($e);
  $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

*Output*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
  <entry>
    <title lang="en">Sample</title>
    <entrydate>0</entrydate>
    <contents>0</contents>
    <entrynum>0</entrynum>
  </entry>

</entries>
```

The items cannot be removed within the first loop, because otherwise we may break the iteration chain. Instead, we collect the entry objects into `$del_items` array, then remove them from XML in separate loop.