# Combine xml tags into one

Tags: php, xml

Is there an easy way to convert xml file tags into one line? my xml file (`$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/locations.xml');`)  contains:

```
<markers>
    <marker>
    <name>Chipotle Minneapolis</name>
    <lat>44.947464</lat>
    <lng>-93.320826</lng>
    <category>Restaurant</category>
    <address>3040 Excelsior Blvd</address>
    <address2></address2>
    <city>Minneapolis</city>
    <state>MN</state>
    <postal>55416</postal>
    <country>US</country>
    <phone>612-922-6662</phone>
    <email>info@chipotle.com</email>
    <web>http://www.chipotle.com</web>
    <hours1>Mon-Sun 11am-10pm</hours1>
    <hours2></hours2>
    <hours3></hours3>
    <featured></featured>
  </marker>
</markers>
```

convert above code to this format:

```
<markers><marker name="Chipotle Minneapolis" lat="44.947464" lng="-93.320826" category="Restaurant" address="3040 Excelsior Blvd" address2="" city="Minneapolis" state="MN" postal="55416" country="US" phone="612-922-6662" email="info@chipotle.com" web="http://www.chipotle.com" hours1="Mon-Sun 11am-10pm" hours2="" hours3="" featured="" features="" /></markers>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy job for [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$string = '<markers>...</markers>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

foreach ($xml->marker as $m) {
    foreach ($m->children() as $c) {
        $m->addAttribute($c->getName(), $c);
        $trash[] = $c;
    }
    foreach ($trash as $t) unset($t[0]);
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

It will work even if you  have multiple `marker` elements. Of course, if
you have  only one  then the  outer loop  is not  needed. Note  that the
elements are removed (by `unset()`) in  a separate iteration not to mess
the main one.

Comment: Regarding `unset($c[0])` and other approaches to removing an element, please read this: [Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262351/remove-a-child-with-a-specific-attribute-in-simplexml-for-php/16062633#16062633)

Answer (score -1):

Put your xml code in `$string` variable and use this code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<markers/>');

$marker = $xml->addChild('marker');

$string = "<markers> ... </markers>";

$string = simplexml_load_string( $string );

foreach( $string->marker->children() as $name => $value )
    $marker->addAttribute( $value->getName(), $value );

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: ... that doesn't even come close to what's being requested... it's supposed to move the child tags of `<marker>` into attributes.

Comment: Not only this does not solve the problem but using regex to deal with xml is not a very good idea!